# Prevent trigger from firing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following trigger

First trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_Update]
ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
    SET  NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @intNewID int

         INSERT INTO [DIENSTLEISTUNG] 
         (DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, 
         PRICE, AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
         AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
         UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE,
         PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ITEMNUMBER,
         PRIORITY, VALID)

         SELECT  i.DESCRIPTION, i.QUANTITY, i.PRICE, i.AZ_MO, 
         i.AZ_DI,i.AZ_MI,i.AZ_DO,i.AZ_FR,       
         i.AZ_SA,i.AZ_SO,i.SERVICETYPE_ID, i.UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),
         i.PERMISSIONS, i.KONTRAKTPOSITION,i.ITEMNUMBER, i.PRIORITY, 'Y'

         FROM INSERTED i
         JOIN deleted d ON i.ID=d.ID
         WHERE i.PRICE<>d.PRICE
         or i.DESCRIPTION<>d.DESCRIPTION


         IF ( UPDATE (PRICE) OR UPDATE (DESCRIPTION) )
         UPDATE  S
         SET  s.VALID = 'N'    
         FROM SERVICE s
         JOIN INSERTED i ON I.ID = S.ID


         IF UPDATE(PRIORITY)
         UPDATE s
         SET s.PRIORITY= i.PRIORITY
         FROM SERVICE s
         JOIN INSERTED i ON i.ID = s.ID

   SET NOCOUNT OFF;      
END
```

The first Trigger copies an entire row with a new ID if a change in the original row happens, also the trigger set a flag. The old row gets the flag `VALID = 'N'` and the new row gets the flag `VALID = 'Y'`. The trigger only creates a new row if `PRICE` or `DESCRIPTION` are updated. So far so good.

My problem is that if I want to update the `PRIORITY` in the new row the trigger fires again and sets the flag to `VALID = 'N'`. That should not happen. I want only to update the priority without creating a new row or update a another column.

Thanks for help

Comment: An excellent example of triggers getting complex quickly.  I'd remove all your triggers, and move the data access to stored procedures that incorporate the trigger functionality.

Comment: iam new in sql and i have no experience with stored procedures. Maybe you can help me with that?

Comment: Stored procedures are easier than triggers.  You can find many good [tutorials on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=+introduction+to+sqlserver+stored+procedure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** prevent a trigger from firing - if it's present and not disabled, **it will fire**. That's how triggers work.

What you *can* do is check inside your trigger which columns have been updated. So you could do something like this in your one single trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_Update]
ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(PRICE) 
      ... (do what you need to do if PRICE is updated)...

    IF UPDATE(DESCRIPTION)
      ... (do what you need to do if DESCRIPTION is updated)...

    IF UPDATE(PRIORITY)
      ... (do what you need to do if PRIORITY is updated)...
```

Use the `UPDATE()` function to check whether a given column has been updated - and if so, act on it. See the [MSDN docs on how to use the `UPDATE()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can make triggers fire only on certain columns or one colomn.
like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_something ON myTable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(myColumn)
BEGIN
--       do what you want
END
```

post below gives more details, seems I'm to slow :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the context info of the session which you are in like this:

```
SET Context_Info 0x55555
```

And then in your trigger check for the context info to decide what to do:

```
DECLARE @Cinfo VARBINARY(128)  
SELECT @Cinfo = Context_Info()  
IF @Cinfo = 0x55555  
    RETURN
```